# data not transfered in response in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am practicing with angular $http for post and get service but my problem my response method is not sending me data back.

here's my script for the same

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')
        .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:8080/app/index.html#/")
        .service('menuFactory',['$http','baseURL' function($http,baseURL) {

            var dishes=[
                         {
                          _id:0,
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                        }                        ];
            var promotions = [
                {
                          _id:0,
                          name:'Weekend Grand Buffet', 
                          image: 'images/buffet.png',
                          label:'New',
                          price:'19.99',
                          description:'Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person ',
                }

            ];

                this.getDishes = function(){

                    return $http.get(baseURL+"dishes");

                };

                this.getDish = function (index) {

                    return $http.get(baseURL,"dishes/"+index;
                };

                    this.getPromotion=function(index){
                        return promotions[index];
                    };

                // implement a function named getPromotion
                // that returns a selected promotion.


        }])

        .factory('corporateFactory', function() {

            var corpfac = {};

            var leadership = [
                {
                    name: "Peter Pan",
                    image: 'images/alberto.png',
                    designation: "Chief Epicurious Officer",
                    abbr: "CEO",
                    description: "Our CEO, Peter, credits his hardworking East Asian immigrant parents who undertook the arduous journey to the shores of America with the intention of giving their children the best future. His mother's wizardy in the kitchen whipping up the tastiest dishes with whatever is available inexpensively at the supermarket, was his first inspiration to create the fusion cuisines for which The Frying Pan became well known. He brings his zeal for fusion cuisines to this restaurant, pioneering cross-cultural culinary connections."
                },
                {
                    name: "Dhanasekaran Witherspoon",
                    image: 'images/alberto.png',
                    designation: "Chief Food Officer",
                    abbr: "CFO",
                    description: "Our CFO, Danny, as he is affectionately referred to by his colleagues, comes from a long established family tradition in farming and produce. His experiences growing up on a farm in the Australian outback gave him great appreciation for varieties of food sources. As he puts it in his own words, Everything that runs, wins, and everything that stays, pays!"
                }                
            ];

        corpfac.getLeaders=function(){
            return leadership;
        }
        corpfac.getLeader=function(index){
            return leadership[index];
        }

        return corpfac;




        })

;
```

controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp')

                              .controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'menuFactory', function($scope, $stateParams, menuFactory) {

                menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($stateParams.id,10));

            $scope.dish ={};
            .then(
            function(response){
                $scope.dish=response.data;
                $scope.showDish=true;
            }
            );

        }])


        .controller('IndexController',['$scope','menuFactory','corporateFactory',function($scope,menuFactory,corporateFactory){
            $scope.promotion=menuFactory.getPromotion(0);
           $scope.leader= corporateFactory.getLeader(3);

          $scope.feturedDish={};
           //  $scope.dish = {};

                        menuFactory.getDish(0)
                        .then(
                            function(response){
                                $scope.feturedDish = response.data;
                                $scope.showDish = true;
                                console.log($scope.feturedDish)
                            }
                        );
 console.log($scope.feturedDish)

        }])

        .controller('AboutController',['$scope','corporateFactory',function($scope,corporateFactory){
            $scope.leaders=corporateFactory.getLeaders();

        }])



;
```

I am using tomcat 8 to  publish this. I read that $http takes json data do I need to send data in that manner??

I got error like this:

```
Error====={"data":"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 - Error report</title><style type=\"text/css\">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /app/index.html/dishes</h1><div class=\"line\"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/app/index.html/dishes</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource is not available.</u></p><hr class=\"line\"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.27</h3></body></html>","status":404,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:8080/app/index.html/dishes","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($stateParams.id,10));

            $scope.dish ={};
            .then( should probably be menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($stateParams.id,10)).then( ... and this "return $http.get(baseURL,"dishes/"+index;" is missing a closing )

Answer (score 0):

Where you have your function(response), I would add the errorcallback, as more likely there is an issue in the call and you are ignoring the error message.

```
menuFactory.getDish(0)
.then(
    function(response){
        $scope.feturedDish = response.data;
        $scope.showDish = true;
        console.log($scope.feturedDish)
    },
    function(reason) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(reason));
    }

    );
```

Do that for the all your getDish calls and more likely you should see an error. Please post the error and we can try to help.

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/unpr?p0=baseURLProvider%20%3C-%20baseURL%20%3C-%20menuFactory` I gave the command you gave but its printing this

Comment: Hmm... I cant seem to reproduce your error... here is a plunker I created based on your code. I am calling the 'IndexController' and it is reading 'index.html' and printing that content in the console. https://plnkr.co/edit/N829VaAUlVVZvScWoMYn?p=preview

Comment: Also looking at this $http.get(baseURL,"dishes/"+index) ... the second parameters is supposed to be a config object. are you trying to do get(baseURL+'dishes/'+index) ?

Comment: The config parameter (of $http.get(ur', config)  passed to the different $http functions controls the HTTP request sent to the server. The config parameter is a JavaScript object which can contain the following properties:

method
url
params
headers
timeout
cache
transformRequest
transformResponse

Comment: I have updated error in question please see once and also update baseURL variable

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm are you getting data while hitting this in your address bar http://localhost:8080/app/index.html#/dishes

Comment: Some part means images and other things are not loaded but I have configured one button it changes values based on true false value button is changing that value